# Delete duplicated records Firebird SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates, firebird

I want to delete duplicated rows, so I used this select statement to find all duplicated rows.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_CARD T1
INNER JOIN( SELECT IDCARD, YEAR FROM MYCARD GROUP BY IDCARD, YEAR HAVING COUNT(IDCARD) > 1 ) T2 ON T1.IDCARD = T2.IDCARD AND T1.YEAR=T2.YEAR
WHERE T1.IDRODZ = 5 AND IDCARD=80;
```

My result looks like that, but this is only short example, there are more duplicated records.

```
 ID   IDCARD    YEAR IDRODZ
 1     80   2014    5
 2     80   2014    5
 3     80   2014    5
 4     80   2015    5
 5     80   2015    5
 6     80   2015    5
```

I need delete statement, that helps me to delete duplicated values, so that my table could look like that:

```
 id  IDCARD   YEAR  IDRODZ
  1  80        2014      5
  4  80        2015      5
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Create a new table. insert select distinct. drop old data. move data back.

Comment: Do you have a unique column in that table e.g. one where the values were generated by a sequence?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i have unique id, i edited my post. maybe i can delete each row that is below max(id)? how?

Comment: Related: http://firebirdfaq.org/faq301/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a unique ID, you can do something like this:

```
delete from my_card
where id not in (select min(id)
                 from my_card
                 group by idcard, year);
```

That will keep the rows with the smallest id for each (idcard, year) combination. If you want to keep the biggest id, use `max(id)` in the sub-select.

Online example: http://rextester.com/WXTU26543