# Firebird Sql Delete Duplicate Record

Tags: sql, duplicates, firebird, sql-delete

How to delete duplicate records?

I am use this query, but it's deleting too much.

```
delete from adaparselkomsulari
where sn not in (select min(sn)
                 from adaparselkomsulari
                 group by sinirtipi, komsuadi);
```

I want to delete the records that are common to the two columns.

[image: look this picture]

Comment: You need to check group counts here, not in will be too broad.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Maybe there is only a `HAVING COUNT(sn) > 1` missing, or whatever exists more then once.

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using?

Comment: I have tried your query on Firebird 2.5 and Firebird 3.0, and they both produce the expected result (note that the expectation in your image that SN = 478 is preserved is wrong, it should be SN = 476). Do you have any indexes on `SINIRTIPI` and/or `KOMSUADI`?

Comment: Note that this seems to duplicate the question [Delete duplicated records Firebird SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802849/delete-duplicated-records-firebird-sql?rq=1), except you are already using the solution from that question.

Comment: @TanveerBadar It won't: the query says 'delete everything that is not the lowest id of its group', so it shouldn't be too broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update one from two of duplicates in Firebird – more rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369633/update-one-from-two-of-duplicates-in-firebird-more-rows)

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
delete from adaparselkomsulari a1
    where exists(select first 1 1 from adaparselkomsulari a2
                 where a2.sinirtipi = a1.sinirtipi and  a2.komsuadi=a1.komsuadi 
                 and a1.sn<>a2.sn)
```

or

```
delete from adaparselkomsulari a1
    where (select count(*) from adaparselkomsulari a2
                 where a2.sinirtipi = a1.sinirtipi and  a2.komsuadi=a1.komsuadi)>1
```